# Does WPF have an easy way to display a navigable series of images?

Tags: wpf, controls, ui-design

I'm making my first WPF application, and its purpose is to generate 6 images from some data. Ideally I'd like to display them in the window, with little "forward" and "back" buttons, and a text indicator for where we are in the image-stack. Kind of like a "mini Windows Photo Gallery."

I think the way to do this might be some kind of customization of the `ListView` styles, but there was also the possibility of using `Frame` with custom WPF pages or something? I dunno, it seems like there should be a canonical way of doing this.

My current best approach is to customize `ListView` following the guidelines of one of my WPF books. If someone's already done this, or if there's a better way, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the [Slide.Show project](http://www.vertigo.com/slideshow.aspx) from Vertigo.  They released the source code for it as a WPF demo application.  The application is a nice image viewer that you can borrow concepts from.  (Microsoft mandated Vertigo to create technology demos for WPF)

Comment: This looks to be the best way to go. Although I would wish for something like this to be built-in---or at least a basic modification---Vertigo is pretty nice, and borrowing concepts from it also works :).